# Trying to ask for confirmation prior to a delete, but alert is triggered by other submits. How can a restrict it to just the delete one?

Tags: php, laravel, form-submit

This button is in the last Colum of every line of a table. When you click delete it passes the ID of the item in that particular row. I just need a way to test that it is indeed the delete button that was clicked.

```
              <form action="{{ route('weapons.destroy',$weapon->id) }}" id="delete"method="post">
                        <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">
                        @csrf
                    <button id="btnDelete" class="button button";>D e l e t e</button>
                    </form>
                </td>
            </tr>
    @endforeach 
</table>
<script>
    document.onsubmit=function(){             
        return confirm('Are you sure? This weapon will be permanently deleted.');
        }

</script>
```

I believe it's a simple thing, I just can't get it.

Comment: fyi, `id` attributes need to be unique in a document. If that code is in every line of a table, you have duplicate `id`s. `class="button button";` Why use the `button` class twice? And remove that `;`. Don't use `document.onsubmit` but only when a delete button is pressed (use `type="button"` on your button)

Comment: you need to listen for your form submit not all of the document

Comment: Each line has a unique it that is passed.  The delete part actually works. The warning works too, it's just that it is displayed when I perform an Add or an edit too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
@foreach ($weapons as $weapon)
    <form class="delete" action="{{ route('weapons.destroy',$weapon->id) }}" method="POST">
        <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">
       @csrf
        <input type="submit" value="Delete">
    </form>
@endforeach

<script>
    $(".delete").on("submit", function(){
        return confirm("Do you want to delete this item?");
    });
</script>
```

I think it would be better to implement Delete Confirmation  with Modal  this link is useful https://dev.to/kingsconsult/how-to-implement-delete-confirmation-in-laravel-8-7-6-with-modal-29c5

Comment: This, works. I'll play will the modal solution too and see what I can do thank you.

Comment: Glad to help you